# using jquery each to show/hide on hover

Tags: jquery, each, onmouseover

I have several links with class "myanchor".
I want to display a div for each link (onmouseover) and hide (onmouseout):

"link1" displays "div1"
"link2" displays "div2"
.
.
.

My code which isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var n = $(".myanchor").length;
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        };

        jQuery.each(arr, function () {
            $("#anchor" + this, "#div" + this).mouseover(function () {
                $("#div" + this).show();
            }).mouseout(function () {
                $("#div" + this).hide();
            });
        });
    });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. I'm assuming the link names are stored in the `id` attribute on the links:

```
$(".myanchor").hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#div" + id.charAt(id.length - 1)).show();
}, function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#div" + id.charAt(id.length - 1)).hide();
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7eGtx/6/). This does away with the need for the `each` loop, because jQuery methods tend to be applied to all elements in the matched set (in this case, that's all the `.myanchor` elements). Using `hover` is just a little bit shorter than binding to `mouseover` and `mouseout` separately, but the end result is the same.

Comment: Thanks, it a clean code, but I also want that when I hover over the div it stays visible, and when I hover off the div it is hidden

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".myanchor").each(function(i){
              $(this).mouseover(function () {
                    $("#div" + i).show();
                }).mouseout(function () {
                    $("#div" + i).hide();
                });
            });
        });
```